# Solaris - Inheriting by files the user's ownership of directory

Tags: permissions, solaris, chown

I have a directory with ownersip like user:group. I want to make on it something like sgid, but for user - all of new created files have a directory ownership. For example:

```
drwxrwx--- 2 user   group   4096 Jun  3 16:10 test
```

And all created files in it have automaticly set following ownership on user:

```
-rwxrw---- 1 user group1 0 Jun  3 16:11 file1
-rwxrw---- 1 user group2 0 Jun  3 16:11 file2
-rwxrw---- 1 user group3 0 Jun  3 16:11 file3
```

It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this. Standard Unix permissions can only go so far, at one point one has to consider using [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

You should consider what needs your system has. If you absolutely need this you should start reading up on ACLs.

[Here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) is the page on Arch Wiki on the subject. Most of this will probably work for any Linux distribution, as well as Solaris since Linux mostly copied Solaris's ACLs.

Comment: Sorry, but the Q is about Solaris, ZFS does not support extended ALC, but it supports NFSv4 ACL. Anyway, I suppose there are no possibility to do what aku asked.

Comment: Oh, sorry, apparently I need to work in my reading! Second time today I do this kind of thing.

Comment: Fortunately, Linux got its ACLs from Solaris, so apart from the part about enabling ACLs, most of the content of the Arch wiki page also applies to Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Solaris allows a non-root user to give away files to another user. So you cannot make newly created files owned by another user: the files will remain owned by the user who created them.

What you can do is arrange for a user to have extra permissions on the files, via an [access control list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list). If you set an ACL entry for user `alice`, then the permissions in that entry will apply instead of the traditional Unix permissions. You can use the [`chmod`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/chmod-1.html#scrolltoc) command or [`setfacl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/setfacl-1.html#scrolltoc) to set ACLs, and [`ls -v](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/ls-1.html#scrolltoc) or [`getfacl`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/getfacl-1.html#scrolltoc) to view the ACL on a file. In addition to the ACL that applies to itself, a directory has a default ACL, which is applied to files newly created in that directory. Thus you need to set the default ACL on the toplevel directory.

```
chmod A+default:user:alice:rwx test
```